# php download file depending on user login

Tags: php, mysql, file, authentication, download

I am a beginner in php programming. i have a running loginscript. what i want is to store files depending on the user. its a membership website and each member has his own documents. when the user logon het gets his own environment and i whant to have his own files avalable for download.  the variable htmlentities($_SESSION['LidID']) is givving the user id. first i have tried to construct a downbload posibility with a prefix of the userid but this is verry insecure. so i am looking to a way of doing this secure. 
with construction is a secure way of storing and downloading only the files that belongs to the logged in user?

i have a mysql database but i dontkwno it its beter to store the files in the database or just in the filesystem(with is insecure because when you have the link you can download it)

Comment: They're only insecure if you put then in a public folder. If you put them somewhere private and only send the data if they're allowed this isn't an issue.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: tadman, thanx for the warning. i have a logon system working based on a proven logon system.  a good friend of my have checked an its save  but thanx for the warning . the location for the download must be public to download i presume otherwise nobody can download it.

Comment: Not really, you can use [`http_send_file`](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-send-file.php) to send arbitrary file data on-demand if you need to lock this down behind an access control layer.